# Get the lowest values greater than zero

Tags: vba, excel

I have the above code, that finds the five max values from a column.
I need to do the same but for the minimum values higher then zero.
I need this to be in VBA because the user can change the values after in the worksheet.

I had already changed max for min, but get errors.

```
Sub best()

Dim maxvalue As Long
Dim copyrow As Long

copyrow = 30
Dim prevval As Long
Dim prevrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim fndrow As Long

prevval = 0
prevrow = 0

For i = 1 To 5

    maxvalue = WorksheetFunction.Large(Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47"), i)
    If maxvalue <> prevval Then
        fndrow = Sheets("Resumo").Range("J11:J47").Find(What:=maxvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    Else
        fndrow = Sheets("Resumo").Range("J" & prevrow & ":J47").Find(What:=maxvalue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End If

    Dim vendor As String

    vendor = Sheets("Resumo").Range("G" & CStr(fndrow))

    Sheets("os melhores").Range("F" & CStr(copyrow)) = maxvalue
    If InStr(vendor, " ") <> 0 Then
        Sheets("os melhores").Range("G" & CStr(copyrow)) = Left(vendor, InStr(vendor, " "))
        Sheets("os melhores").Range("H" & CStr(copyrow)) = Right(vendor, InStr(vendor, " "))
    Else
        Sheets("os melhores").Range("G" & CStr(copyrow)) = Sheets("Resumo").Range("G" & CStr(fndrow))
    End If

    prevval = maxvalue
    prevrow = fndrow

    copyrow = copyrow + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

[File](http://www.filedropper.com/test_27)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line you got the errors..

Comment: In: 'fndrow = Sheets("Resumo").Range("J" & prevrow & ":J47").Find(What:=MinValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row Run time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: what version of excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub best()
    Dim copyrow As Long
    Dim helpRng  As Range

    copyrow = 30
    With Worksheets("Resumo")
        With .Range("J11:J47")
            Set helpRng = .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
            helpRng.Value = .Value
            helpRng.Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, -7).Value
            Set helpRng = helpRng.Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, 2).Offset(-1)
        End With
    End With

    With helpRng
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 2) = "header"
        .Sort key1:=helpRng, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            Worksheets("os melhores").Cells(copyrow, "F").Resize(5, 2).Value = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Resize(5).Value
            Worksheets("os melhores").Cells(copyrow, "G").Resize(5).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

and change `order1:=xlAscending` to `order1:=xlDescending` to have the top five highest values report in "os melhores" worksheet

Comment: After run it, the rows with data in sheets "Resumo" 'disapeared'!. In the other sheets the values copied, but now it the vendor name, appears whole name and no longer first & last.

Comment: in my tests nothing similar happens. show your minimal data structure reproducing the problem. In "os melhores" sheet, first the vendor names are pasted in column "G" from row 30 downwards and then what's in those pasted column "G" cells gets splitted in as many adjacent columns as spaces (" ") in it

Comment: 'Disapeared' = the cells are hidden with the filter, When removed the filter they apeared, but if i ran the code again it gives error. 'No data was selected to parse'.

Comment: Can i sent you the file?

Comment: post the link in your question

Comment: is in the end of question

Comment: everything works except that names are in column "C" instead of "G" as I got from your post. I edited my post to account for vendor names in column "C"

Comment: You are very good with this! I just need one thing more, that i forgot to mencion in the question. I only want to display the first and last name in one cell and the values must apear in order by value, first 4 then three ....

Comment: Glad to be of help.  As per this site rules 1) new issues must be posted in new questions with your code attempts 2) please mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you

Comment: Done. I tried do get a up value in the arrow, but i still can not do it. But here i express my appreciation to you and to your skills ! I will post a nrw question. I will use the code you gave to me. I hope you dont be angry. thanks again for your help.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer. you cannot upvote till you have 50 reps. of course you can use my code for yours subsequent questions, but to increase the probability of getting help you must show efforts on your part (i.e. do some coding to reach your new goal) and explain people what didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a macro to solve this question or your original question about the top 5.  You can use an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7).

Please see this screen shot for reference:

[image]

Setup:

- A1:A7 has data, you will need to update with your range
- C2 has the formula in C3
- C3:C7 have the top 5 largest values
- D2 has the formula in D3
- D3:D7 have the top 5 small values that are greater than 0

Taking the Max as an example, put the formula in cell C3 and press enter.  You will then get the largest number.  From there highlight cell C3 and press shift down 4 times so you highlight the next 4 rows.  Then go into the formula bar and click the formula like you want to edit it.  From there press ctrl+shift+enter (PC) command+enter (apple, I think) and it will fill in the remaining cells.  They will update as you change the values in the referenced range.

Here is a screen shot of what it should look like to do the array formula:

[image]

As you can see, the cell with the formula is the main cell with focus while the next 4 cells are highlighted.  The cursor is in the formula box and then press the ctrl+shift+enter.

Minor Update:

You don't even need an array formula to solve the largest 5.  You could just set each excel to LARGE(A1:A7, 1) then the next cell as LARGE(A1:A7, 2) then the next cell as LARGE(A1:A7, 3), etc..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, I think the error is caused by that if you change WorksheetFunction.Large to WorksheetFunction.Small (which you did, right?) then maxvalue can be 0, so 0 is not a dedicated 'invalid value' anymore. You can do one of the following:

1. declare maxvalue as variant and use a different value to mean invalid, e.g. "n/a", examine if maxvalue is this one in the first If.
2. (and this also helps to filter out 0's and negative values) The first parameter of WorksheetFunction.Large should be another Worksheet function that excludes, negative (or non-positive values), like you would do it in a formula:

   =IF( 0 < a, a, bignumber )
3. Write an algorithm to store the values and the line numbers into a fixed size array.

Comment: No, I don,t use small. I only changed large to min, like 'WorksheetFunction.Min'. I didnt understant the other thing you wrote.

Comment: So, first of all, to use this same macro, you need to change Large to Small because now you don't want to find the i-th largest but the i-th smallest element, right?. Large( Range, 3 ) finds the 3rd largest element in Range, Small( Range, 3 ) finds the 3rd smallest element in Range.